# Inconsistent jQuery event handling for jQuery UI sortable widget

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

There's something I don't understand regarding jQuery event handling. I discovered this issue while working with the jQuery UI [sortable widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable). I was attempting to trigger a sort event on the widget.

Let's say I have a simple HTML list:

```
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

I began by attempting to trigger the sort event like this:

```
$('ul').sortable({
  start: function() { console.log("drag started"); }
});

// No output to the console from this line
$('ul').trigger('sortstart');
```

Is there something wrong with this code? The start callback function isn't called... Is there no way to trigger this callback? However, I discovered that the following does work:

```
$('ul').sortable();
$('ul').on('sortstart', function() { console.log('drag started'); });

// This line does cause the console to output 'drag started'
$('ul').trigger('sortstart');
```

I'm curious to know why the first attempt failed.

Comment: You may have triggered the event, however you didn't trigger the plugin's sortstart method. As far as i know, there's no way of doing that using the built-in api, you'd have to get access to the plugin's methods (which shouldn't be that difficult, `console.log($(element).data())`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**jQuery-UI Widget Events**

jQuery-UI uses a prefix for all the events that its widgets trigger. For the ui.sortable widget the `widgetEventPrefix` is `sort`. This is part of the initialization information for the sortable widget taken right from the jQuery-ui code:

```
widgetEventPrefix: "sort"
```

So when the sortable widget calls `trigger()` internally for a `start` event it fires a `sortstart` event (the composite), but it doesn't mean it's necessarily listening for that event.

**Example 1**

This first example tells jQuery to wire up a callback to the start method of the sortable widget. This will get called internally when the start method is invoked. The trigger portion of the code (`$('ul').trigger('sortstart')`) is just triggering an event that happens to have the same name as an event that jQuery-ui triggers internally. jQuery-UI is not listening for this event and will not be invoked in any way by this trigger.

**Example 2**

The second example is wiring up an event handler to an event that is triggered immediately after; however this is never actually invoking the sortable widget's internal code.

Comment: Great answer. Is there a way to trigger the internal 'sortstart' event? In other words, is there a good way to fake the start or stop of a drag?

Comment: Well the functions themselves are internal to the widget but you could trigger events on the sortable element which would indirectly trigger the methods. Triggering the `mousedown` event on a sortable element should invoke the _mouseStart method, but since this is not the intended use of the methods you might right into some exceptions due to lack of event information (all the DOM information jQuery collects on an event).

Comment: Thank you my friend